# Best way to set timer in React/Redux for sending refresh auth token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, redux, jwt

I'm using the access refresh jwt authentication flow and want the client to send a refresh token to get a new access token every 10 minutes after it received the access token. I also want to make sure that if the user closes their laptop for an hour and comes back to it that a new access token request is also sent. What is the best way to implement this behavior in React/redux, where the user will always have a valid access token and seamlessly keeps their "session" going?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To achieve that you can conditionnally check the expiration of the token before each request instead of setting a timer.

This will depend on the way you communicate with the server but the idea is to store client side the jwt token, his expiration and the refresh token (and his expiration too if needed) then use some sort of middleware before each request that need the auth :

```
const authClientMiddleware = (done) => {
    if (new Date(localStorage.getItem('expiration')) <= new Date()) {
        getNewToken(localStorage.getItem('refreshToken')).then(() => done()).catch(() => logout());
    } else {
        done();
    }
}
```

Comment: what about if you have multiple requests happening. In a react app could be that you have different panels and all of them are load with api data.